# $Y \sim β(n,m)$ Find the moment generating function of $−\log Y$.

Tags: probability-theory

## Problem

Let $Y \sim β(n,m)$ ($n$, $m$ integers).

(a) Compute the moment generating function of $−\log Y$.

(b) Show that $-\log Y$ has the same distribution as
the sum of m number of $X_k$, where all $X_k$ are independent, exponentially distributed random variables.

Note to self: k3p5.

## Attempt

I go straight at the defn of moment generating function, but I do not know how to handle the integral. Wolfram Alpha did not give anything. I try to "find" the gamma distr since I believe that's what we are looking for (see question b).

[image]

Comment: Your part (b) is quite unclear.  You're saying $-\log Y$ has the same distribution as..... something.  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X \in \beta (n,m)$ where $n$ and $m$ are integers and let $X_k \in \exp(n+k)$ be independent for $ k \leq m-1$. We want to compute

1. The moment generating function of $Y = -\ln X$ .
2. Show that $Y$  has the same distribution as $Z = \sum_0 ^{m-1} X_k$

We start by computing
$$
 Y = -\ln X \Leftrightarrow  e^{-Y} = X  
$$
since 
$$
f_X(x)= \frac{1}{B(n,m)}x^{n-1}(1-x)^{m-1}
$$
we get that
$$
\psi_Y(-t)=E[e^{-tY}]=E[X^{t}]= \frac{1}{B(n,m)}\int_0 ^1 y^{n+t-1}(1-y)^{m-1} dy= \frac{B(n+t,m)}{B(n,m)}
$$
Where
$$
B(n,m) = \frac{(n-1)!(m-1)!}{(n+m-1)!} \text{ and } B(n+t,m) = \int_0 ^1 y^{n+t-1}(1-y)^{m-1} dy 
$$
from known properties of the Beta function we conclude (se wikipedia for example)
$$
\psi_X(-t)= \frac{B(n+t,m)}{B(n,m)} =\frac{\Gamma(n+t)\Gamma(m) \Gamma(n+m)}{\Gamma(n+m+t)\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)}=\frac{\Gamma(n+t)\Gamma(n+m)}{\Gamma(n+m+t)\Gamma(n)}
$$
From the equality 
$$
\frac{\Gamma(t+s)}{\Gamma(t)}= (t+s-1) \times (t+s-2) \times \dots \times (t+1) \times t
$$
and
$$
\psi_X(t)=\frac{\Gamma(n-t)\Gamma(n+m)}{\Gamma(n+m-t)\Gamma(n)} 
$$
we get that
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n-t)\Gamma(n+m)}{\Gamma(n+m-t)\Gamma(n)} = \frac{(n+m-1) \times (n+m-2) \times \dots \times (n+1) \times n}{(n+m-t-1) \times (n+m-t-2) \times \dots \times (n+1-t) \times (n-t)}
$$
hence
$$
\psi_X(t) = \prod _{k = 0}^{m-1} (\frac{n+k}{n+k-t})=\prod _{k = 0}^{m-1} (1-\frac{t}{n+k})^{-1}
$$
which proves that $X$ follows the same distribution as $Z = \sum_0 ^{m-1} X_k$